# JSON not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the code I am using to get the JSON response from PHP:

```
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#image-upload-form').ajaxForm({
    dataType: null,
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
        //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
        var responseJSON = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
        //var responseJSON = eval('('+xhr.responseText+')');

        /*var DOMElement = $(".progress-block-template").clone();
        var pagename = typeof($("#pagename").attr('value')=='undefined')?'':$("#pagename").attr('value');
        processingData(responseJSON,DOMElement,pagename);*/
    }
}); 

})();
```

And here is the response getting while printing using `.html()`.

```
{
    "data": {
        "thumb_location": "http://XXXX.com/private/U/367/catalog/3/16285/thumbs/220x220.jpg?Expires=1349242125&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIGM4K33RYJKUHOXA&Signature=ptphhyF2GL6xe7xeosrzfKkpsXm7fWQAapcF3rjsZMuTwSCMhj2SZDIKtKGZ35-OJjTJ1LXu7wGEQlQvdKrBqT2oiOcPtL7etgTzRLe4~ub3KF64HhkglKv4DgzAWfvG5v8rNfmFvSja3HQ4K8m2o3h0Tl1uv7Lbwpqq0p71L5M_",
        "user_id": "367",
        "category_id": "3",
        "category_type": "worksample",
        "asset_id": 16285,
        "project_id": null,
        "file_name": "Chrysanthemum_37726.jpg",
        "size": 879394
    },
    "success": "true"
}
```

But if I do `$.parseJSON` or `eval` to parse the JSON response, it terminates the execution there itself. This is happening only in IE and it is working properly in FF and Chrome.

Comment: *What* exception and *which* version(s) of IE? - Please put this in before I get bored and down-vote for "doesn't work" syndrome. Also, can create a *minimal* jsfiddle test-case that shows this behavior with the data supplied?

Comment: Support for IE 8 and above has been removed in JQuery 2.0 and upwards. It might work now but you might face some consistency issues later refer: [link1](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/) [link2](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/07/13/1936205/jquery-20-will-drop-support-for-ie-6-7-8) <br> I'd go with the javascript native api's for AJAX data transfers

Comment: @CrystalPaladin Considering jQuery 2.0 is still not officially available (until *at least* sometime in 2013) and jQuery 1.8/1.9 will be supported indefinitely, I don't think it's much of a concern. Thus, the suggestion of "doing it manually" *is not justified and wasteful of development time*. Please take time to read the full articles in the posted links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the datatype should be `json`

```
 dataType: "json",
```

in `IE` this cause problem when you don't specify the dataType.

and also try to change `application/json; charset=utf8` to just plain `application/json`.

Comment: That will make sure that the response is automatically converted *from* JSON (which is awesome) - but, given the data above (which is presumed to be collected accurately),  why would it make a difference when converting the JSON manually?